# Photoshop's Auto-Levels,Contrasts / Picasa's feeling lucky

Tags: image-processing

would anyone be aware of a good library (free or not) to do the equivalent of Photoshop's auto contrats/levels or Picasa's feeling luckly?

I am trying to correct pictures automatically in a batch.

I tried AForge.net, which is pretty cool but gives some disastrous results (sample below)

Before:
http://cmichel.net/so/before.jpg

After (Aforge):
http://cmichel.net/so/After-Aforge.jpg

Best regards

Comment: It has improved the contrast, but it's affected the hue as well. Have you tried replacing the hue channel in your After-Aforge image with the original hue channel? This might retain the contrast improvement without altering the hue.

Comment: have you tried this? http://www.colour-science.com/i2e_library/i2e%20libraries.htm

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate colour-science.com, it looks interesting. Dan: how do you replace the Hue channel? Replacing a RGB channel seems easy (http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/834163cc-bcbd-7fd9-995a-c2c50189e657.htm) but I can't find a filter for Hue.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic contrast improvement is frequently done by Histogram Equalization (AKA Histogram Normalization). (usually its done on grayscale images or the Intensity channel of an HSI color model)

Keep in mind, while this is in general a good means of improving contrast, it doesnt always work. It has better performance if you did Local Histogram Eq on some images.

Decent PPT slides on topic:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.bgu.ac.il%2F~klara%2FATCS111%2FIntensity%2520Transformation%2520and%2520Spatial%2520Filtering%2520-Gonzales%2520Chapter%25203.1-3.3.ppt&ei=loB0T_yPMcro0QGN7PX_Ag&usg=AFQjCNEKzlqkIsnHqTmY8xkgLBfDLplE-w&sig2=C6CrU9nWuKCXif0V8KayQg

Comment: while histogram equalization is a very scientific approach to contrast enhancement, I am not sure that it is used in programs like photoshop and picasa, mainly because nothing proves that a flat histogram leads to nicer images (quite the opposite). A prefered method is to estimate a black point, a white point, and a gamma, compute the corresponding tone curve, and apply it to the image.